# Game works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but zero functionality on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I made the child's game Simon on Codepen. It loads and has functionality on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but zero functionality on Safari (although it does load onto the page).

I get the following error message in the console: `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'safari.application.addEventListener') global code (main.js, line 1)`

Putting `console.log("check")` even in the first line of the Javascript file does not get logged in the console.

Does anyone know what's going on or how I can fix this?

Here's a link to the Codepen and my Javascript code below:
https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/oEoYpw

```
let computerArr;
let playerArr;
let myLightFunc = null; // lights up button upon click
let myDarkFunc = null; // re-darkens button after a second
let i; // iterator through the playerArr
let active = true; // if true, computer sequence is active and player cannot press buttons

let c; // count

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mousedown", buttonClicked, false);
  buttons[i].addEventListener("mouseup", buttonUp, false);
}

let reset = document.getElementById("reset");
reset.addEventListener("click", initialize, false);

let strict = document.getElementById("strict");
strict.addEventListener("click", strictMode, false);  // change button background color when true
let s = false; // strict mode

let context = new AudioContext();

let audioblue = context.createOscillator();
let b = context.createGain();
b.gain.value = 0;
audioblue.frequency.value = 329.63;
audioblue.type = "sine";
audioblue.connect(b);
b.connect(context.destination);
audioblue.start();

let audiored = context.createOscillator();
let r = context.createGain();
r.gain.value = 0;
audiored.frequency.value = 261.63;
audiored.type = "sine";
audiored.connect(r);
r.connect(context.destination);
audiored.start();

let audiogreen = context.createOscillator();
let g = context.createGain();
g.gain.value = 0;
audiogreen.frequency.value = 220;
audiogreen.type = "sine";
audiogreen.connect(g);
g.connect(context.destination);
audiogreen.start();

let audioyell = context.createOscillator();
let y = context.createGain();
y.gain.value = 0;
audioyell.frequency.value = 164.81;
audioyell.type = "sine";
audioyell.connect(y);
y.connect(context.destination);
audioyell.start();

let audioerr = context.createOscillator();
let e = context.createGain();
e.gain.value = 0;
audioerr.frequency.value = 110;
audioerr.type = "triangle";
audioerr.connect(e);
e.connect(context.destination);
audioerr.start();

function strictMode() {
  s = !s;
  if (s) {
    document.getElementById("strict").style.cssText = "background-color: #ffce00";
  }

  else {
     document.getElementById("strict").style.cssText = "background-color: #a9b53a";
  }
}

function initialize() {
  stopLight(); // if light sequence is running, clear it (if start is pressed in middle of computer sequence)
  computerArr = [];
  playerArr = [];
  c = 0; // count
  i = 0; // iterator through playerArr
  start();
}

function start() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  switch (rand) { // convert to text so that array items will align with HTML IDs
    case 0:
      computerArr.push("zero");
      break;

    case 1:
      computerArr.push("one");
      break;

    case 2:
      computerArr.push("two");
      break;

    case 3:
      computerArr.push("three");
      break;
  }

  c++;
  $(".inner").html(c);
  console.log(computerArr);
  beginInterval();
}

function beginInterval() {
  active = true; // computerArr sequence is beginning
  i = 0;
  let interval = 1800;
  if (c > 12) { // increase speed as count increases
    interval = 1050;
  }

  else if (c > 8) {
    interval = 1200;
  }

  else if (c > 5) {
    interval = 1500;
  }

  myLightFunc = setInterval(function() {lightUp(computerArr);}, interval);

}

// handle all beeps and light ups
// called during computerArr sequence and on user click
function beepIn(q) { // takes a string
    let elem = document.getElementById(q);
  switch(q) {
    case "zero":
      b.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.015);
      $(elem).css("background-color","#1c8cff");
      break;

    case "one":
      r.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.015);
      $(elem).css("background-color","#ff4c4c");
      break;

    case "two":
      g.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.015);
      $(elem).css("background-color","#13ff7c");
      break;

    case "three":
      y.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.015);
      $(elem).css("background-color","#fed93f");
      break;
  }
}


function lightUp(arr) {
  beepIn(arr[i]);

  let quad = arr[i];

  myDarkFunc = setInterval(function() {darkDown(quad);}, 1000);
  i++;
  if (i == computerArr.length) {
    setTimeout(function() { active = false }, 1050); // wait addtl 50ms from until myDarkFunc is finished
    stopLight(myLightFunc);
  }
}

function darkDown(btn) { // takes a string
  let elem = document.getElementById(btn);
  if (btn == "zero") {
    b.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.015)
    $(elem).css("background-color","#023991");
  }
  else if (btn == "one") {
    r.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.015);
    $(elem).css("background-color","#910202");
  }
  else if (btn == "two") {
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.015);
    $(elem).css("background-color","#008e02");
  }
  else if (btn == "three") {
    y.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.015);
    $(elem).css("background-color","#ccc000");
  }
  clearInterval(myDarkFunc); // clears interval 'start'ed each time through lightUp
}

function stopLight() {
  clearInterval(myLightFunc);
}

function buttonClicked(square) {
  if (!active) { // only allow button clicks when computer sequence is inactive
    let pushed = square.target.id;
    playerArr.push(pushed);
    let x = compare();
    if (!x) { // if wrong click
      setTimeout(function() {
        e.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, context.currentTime, 0.015);
    }, 33);
      setTimeout(function() {
        e.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime, 0.015);
      }, 950);
      if (s) { // if wrong click and also in strict mode
        gameOver();
      }
      else { // if wrong click but not in strict mode
        console.log("Try again");
        playerArr = [];
        stopLight(myLightFunc); // stop computer sequence
        beginInterval();
      }
    }
    else {
      beepIn(pushed); // handle beep and light up
    }

    console.log(playerArr);
  }
}

function buttonUp(square) {
  if (!active) {
    let pushed = square.target.id;
    darkDown(pushed); // end beep and re-darken button
    if (playerArr.length == computerArr.length) { // if correct array, clear playerArr and pick new number for computerArr
      playerArr = []
      start();
    }
  } // if playerArr len is not yet == to computerArr len, no code is executed, program simply waits for another button to be pushed by user
}

function compare() {
  let i = playerArr.length - 1; // check most recent entry
  return playerArr[i] == computerArr[i];
}

function gameOver() {
  computerArr = [];
  playerArr = [];
  active = true; // prevents further player clicks
  console.log("You lose");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like Safari cannot run CodePen at all? Try creating a new CodePen with something super simple such as `alert( 'hi!' );`. Does it work?

Comment: The only uses of jQuery in this code that I see are `html()` (which you could use element.innerHTML = newValue) and `css()` (which you could use element.style.key = newValue).  For the limited amount of jQuery you are using in this logic, i'd advise refactoring those usages out and remove the library from the script.  Most likely not your issue, but just an observation.

Comment: Does safari allow you to click on something that takes you to the actual line of the code that causes the error (with source maps and prettyfied) like Chrome does?

Comment: @HMR doesn't seem to. Error message is saying the error is at line 1 and even if I console.log something at line 1 it's not showing up.

Comment: Maybe use Babel, in settings -> JavaScript -> JavaScript preprocessor -> select Babel. Then click run again.

Comment: @HMR That kinda helped actually. It's not fully functional but now if the user presses a button I can at least have an alert that tells them the game doesn't work on Safari. Using Babel also fixed other apps of mine that worked fine on other browsers but not on Safari. Any idea why this would've helped?

Comment: @Scott Babel transpiles code you write ES6 to an older version of ES so browsers that don't support certain syntax can run your code.